# Выборка с предыдущим значением в виртуальном столбце

Tags: php, mysql

Исходный запрос

```
    $sql = "SELECT date, val1, val2, val3
            FROM `$table`
            ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Нужно сделать запрос аналогичный исходному с 3мя дополнительными виртуальными столбцами содержащими предыдущие значение (если они есть), что-то вроде этого:

```
    $sql2 = "SELECT date, val1, val2, val3, prev_val1, prev_val2, prev_val3
            FROM `$table`
            ORDER BY date ASC";
```

ИЛИ что более идеально, запрос содержащий разницу между текущим и предыдущим значением.

```
    $sql3 = "SELECT date, (val1 - prev_val1) AS val12, (val2 - prev_val2) AS val22, (val3 - prev_val3) AS val32
            FROM `$table`
            ORDER BY date ASC";
```

В ячейках если и содержаться значения то целочисленные.
Могут отсутствовать NULL или быть равны 0.
НЕ отрицательные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date,
       val1-@pval1 as diff1, val2-@pval2 as diff2, val3-@pval3 as diff3,
       @pval1:=val1 as val1, @pval2:=val2 as val2, @pval3:=val3 as val3
  FROM `$table`, (select @pval1:=NULL, @pval2:=NULL, @pval3:=NULL) A
 ORDER BY date ASC
```

Переменные должны получать новые значения *после* того как будут использованы их предыдущие значения. Потому как все действия выполняются слева на право. Сначала вычисляется `val1-@pval1`, а потом переменной `@pval1` присваивается значение из текущей строки, что бы остаться в ней до следующей.

Comment: Спасибо, работает идеально! Для чего буква "A" перед ORDER?

Comment: @Andrey Это название(алиас) подзапроса который перед ней в скобках. MySQL требует что бы имя было

Answer (score 1):

В MS SQL и DB2 есть специальная функция для этого — lag(). В MySQL можно выкрутиться через сохранение значения в переменную. Вот пример из англоязычного SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11316349/272885
ну и другие аналогичные примеры гуглятся по фразе "mysql simulate lag"