# Анализ записей таблицы и очистка от невалидных данных

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток

Есть следующая таблица:

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `data`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, /* ID записи */
  `station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,        /* ID измерительной станции */
  `box_id` int(11) NOT NULL,            /* ID измерительного блока на станции */
  `param_id` int(11) NOT NULL,          /* Код измеренного параметра */
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,             /* Значение измеренного параметра */
  `tm` bigint(20) NOT NULL,             /* Метка времени, когда был получен измеренный параметр */
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Если кратко, то таблица хранит измерения неких параметров (целые числа `value`) для нескольких станций `station_id` измерения параметров. Внутри станции может быть несколько измерительных блоков `box_id`, и параметры они меряют тоже разные - `param_id`. Про получении данных записывается время в `tm`.

Записи могут быть примерно вот такими:

```
id     station_id box_id param_id value tm
906616 2          1      5        2100  1500270962
906616 2          2      2        2199  1500270960
906616 2          3      3        2850  1500270960
```

Ну и подобный числовой хаос, который без поллитры не понятен. Тем не менее каждая запись важна, и по ним строятся всякие графики, отчеты и прочий анализ.

Количество записей в таблице порядка 2-3 миллионов и возрастает. Записи годичной давности вынимаются из этой таблицы и перекладываются в архивные таблицы по ежемесячному cron.

К сути. Измерительное оборудование сгорело. Несколько станций записали в нескольких своих блоках вместо нормальных измерений нули и единицы (а возможно, и что-то еще нехорошее, но никак не похожее на нормальные измерения).

Задача: найти невалидные данные и уничтожить (удалить из таблицы), при этом не задев валидные данные.

Для тех параметров, которые выдают случайные с точки зрения человека данные, это невозможно - тут ничего не попишешь. Но есть параметры, которые имеют определенный закон - проще говоря, постоянно возрастают. Причем возрастают они гарантированно для одного измерительного прибора - то есть если взять

```
SELECT `value` FROM `data` WHERE `station_id` = 1,`box_id` = 1,`param_id` = 1 ORDER BY `tm` DESC;
```

то `value` будет отсортированным массивом (если данные валидны). Но это не так по факту - есть вкрапления невалидных данных

Вот собственно и суть вопроса, по которому я обращаюсь. Нужно сочинить такой SQL запрос, который сумеет выбрать все записи с определенным значением индекса [`station_id`,`box_id`,`param_id`], у которых начался сбой - то есть значение `A`.`value` стало меньше чем `B`.`value`, при этом `A`.`tm` больше `B`.`tm`, то есть значение было получено позже и уменьшилось относительно предыдущего.

Умом я понимаю, что нужно сделать. Есть рабочее решение на PHP, которые выбирает блок измерений, который может прожевать, и в коде смотрит, все ли в порядке, удаляя невалидные данные. Недостаток этого решение в длительности обработки и в необходимости лопатить все данные, вместо только нужных участков. Второй недостаток - данные постоянно пополняются, и нет уверенности в определенный момент времени, что таблица очищена от сбоев, поскольку скрипт может обработать только небольшую часть данных. Нельзя сказать, что если скрипт ничего не сделал, то данные валидны и возрастают - потому что скрипт не может охватить все данные сразу, а только небольшое окно от сих до сих. На мой взгляд для этого как раз нужен SQL.

Результатом работы SQL запроса я вижу `id` записей, в которых обнаружен сбой. Если таких записей нет и запрос вернул пустоту, значит вся таблица валидна и сбоев нет. Можно убрать поллитру и открыть шампанское.

Я не силен в сочинении сложных SQL, обычно хватает маленьких. Сам язык знаю на базовом уровне - выборка из двух-трех таблиц, вставка, удаление. Но тут совсем необычная ситуация обработки данных.

UPD: После длительных поисков в итоге оформил решение через более умный скрипт на php, который анализирует скорость прироста величины за промежуток времени, и при резком изменении скорости прироста считает новые значения плохими. Через SQL решить задачу так и не удалось. Решение со скриптом имеет один существенный минус - оно антинаучно, величины прироста и пороги выбраны эмпирически и ничем не доказаны. Короче говоря, костыль

Comment: А оборудование не может начать вдруг отсчет опять с нуля или выдать некорректное слишком большое значение после которого опять вернутся к нормальным более низким показателям ? На вскидку `select .. from data A where exists(select 1 from data B where B.station_id=A.station_id and B.box_id=A.box_id na A.param_id=B.param_id and B.tm<A.tm and B.value>A.value` правда для удаления так нельзя, надо на обчный join переделывать, а он может оказаться слишком тормозным в такой ситуации.

Comment: Может стоит искать аномальные отклонения в разные стороны, на слишком большую величину, например. правда для этого надо будет сначала собрать статистику в разрезе показателей, что является нормой

Comment: Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588528/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B5/588530#588530 есть пример работы с значением из предыдущей записи. Используя переменные можно сделать за один проход по таблице фактически то же, что делает цикл в php

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM data t1 JOIN data t2 
ON (t1.tm<t2.tm AND t1.value>t2.value) 
WHERE t1.station_id = 1 AND t1.box_id = 1 AND t1.param_id = 1 AND t2.station_id = 1 AND t2.box_id = 1 AND t2.param_id = 1;
```

Comment: Попробую, но мне кажется, что на выборке value например `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 11, 12` решение даст не совсем то, что ожидалось.. я уже писал что-то вроде этого, до того как задать вопрос )