# Как быстро получить пропущенное в поле значение?

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица `sample`. Важный уникальный индекс `UNIQUE( laboratory_prefix_id, sample_number )`. Последний задаёт группу, в пределах которой не может быть повторяющихся `sample_number`. Вопрос следующий - как быстро получить список пропущенных `sample_number` в пределах запрошенной группы `laboratory_prefix_id`? И если не список, то хотя бы 1 наименьшее значение.

Например, если искать в группе `laboratory_prefix_id=5`, то максимальный `sample_number=15`, но перед ним пропущены значения 11, 12, 13, 14 - их (или хотя бы значение 11) хотелось бы как-то получить (т.е. получить просто `sample number` пропущенных значений). Как это быстро сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дамп таблицы для примера прикладываю

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` ( 
    `id` Int( 10 ) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `person_id` Int( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `laboratory_prefix_id` TinyInt( 3 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `sample_number` Smallint( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `total_cost` Decimal( 6, 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `completion_date` Date NULL,
    `barcode` VarChar( 15 ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL,
    `country_id` TinyInt( 3 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '20',
    `sample_priority` TinyInt( 1 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `sample_note` VarChar( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL,
    `registration_date` Date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ),
    CONSTRAINT `UK_sample` UNIQUE( `laboratory_prefix_id`, `sample_number` ) )
CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci
COMMENT 'Образцы'
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 57;

INSERT INTO `sample`(`id`,`person_id`,`laboratory_prefix_id`,`sample_number`,`total_cost`,`registration_date`,`completion_date`,`barcode`,`country_id`,`sample_priority`,`sample_note`) VALUES 
( '15', '120', '8', '155', '0.00', '2017-08-18', NULL, '12-55fff', '20', '3', 'sdfsdfsdf' ),
( '22', '120', '7', '1', '0.00', '2017-08-11', NULL, NULL, '20', '1', NULL ),
( '32', '120', '7', '10', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '1', NULL ),
( '33', '165', '5', '1', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '2', NULL ),
( '34', '165', '5', '2', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '2', NULL ),
( '35', '166', '5', '3', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '3', NULL ),
( '36', '166', '5', '4', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '3', NULL ),
( '37', '167', '5', '5', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '2', '6лоло' ),
( '38', '168', '5', '6', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '1', NULL ),
( '39', '168', '5', '7', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '1', NULL ),
( '40', '168', '5', '8', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '1', NULL ),
( '41', '168', '5', '9', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '1', NULL ),
( '42', '168', '5', '10', '0.00', '2017-08-19', NULL, NULL, '20', '1', NULL ),
( '43', '173', '7', '2', '0.00', '2017-08-20', NULL, 'к', '17', '2', 'ккк' ),
( '44', '173', '5', '15', '0.00', '2017-08-18', NULL, 'ne', '20', '2', '=' ),
( '47', '180', '8', '5', '0.00', '2017-08-20', NULL, NULL, '20', '2', NULL ),
( '49', '120', '8', '161', '0.00', '2017-08-18', NULL, '12-55fff', '20', '2', 'sdfsdfsdf' ),
( '54', '120', '6', '212', '0.00', '2017-09-01', NULL, NULL, '20', '2', NULL ),
( '55', '120', '6', '213', '0.00', '2017-09-01', NULL, NULL, '20', '3', NULL ),
( '56', '120', '6', '214', '0.00', '2017-09-01', NULL, NULL, '20', '2', NULL );
```

Comment: поле prefix_id в индексе сделать первым. И можно что нибудь сделать с помощью переменных, сравнивать предыдущие значения с текущими https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588528/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B5/588530#588530

Comment: @Mike Так и есть. Тут не в том порядке указал. А ссылку посмотрю

Comment: Или как вариант завести таблицу с порядковыми номерами от 1 до максимально возможного и подклеить к ней по LEFT JOIN выборку по нужной группе. все номера к которым ничего не приклеилось и есть искомые

Comment: @Mike нашёл интересный вариант в самом конце статьи - https://habrahabr.ru/post/228099/ , но не выходит под себя прикрутить

Comment: На всякий случай - проглядывайте все найденные решения на предмет работоспособности в случаях: 1) отсутствует запись с начальным значеним (как правило, это значение 1); 2) Отсутствуют записи в принципе. Код с Хабра не сработает ни в первом, ни во втором случаях. Видимые универсальные решения: 1) использование опорной таблицы чисел, как рекомендует @Mike; 2) нумерация записей с использованием переменных и выборкой первой записи, где номер не совпадает с индексом.

Comment: @n.osennij В самом конце той статьи все таки с подзапросом, хотя и щадящим. что то вроде `select sample_number-1 from sample A where not exists(select 1 from sample B where B.sample_number=A.sample_number-1 and B.laboratory_prefix_id=A.laboratory_prefix_id) and laboratory_prefix_id=XX` только он даст ближайшее отсутствующее значение, но не количество. Вопрос в том, что с этими числами надо дальше делать.

Comment: С подзапросоами можно еще пару вариантов придумать, в том числе дающие диапазоны отсутствующих. только это все таки будет немного тяжелее, чем переменные.

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT @count
FROM sample, (select @count := 0) dummy
WHERE sample.laboratory_prefix_id = 5
  AND (@count := @count+1) < sample.sample_number
ORDER BY sample.sample_number ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Не работает в случае, если для заданного sample.laboratory_prefix_id нет ни одной записи.

Если начальное значение не равно 1, следует откорректировать как псевдотаблицу dummy, так и условие во WHERE. Вот более универсальный запрос (соответствует условию типа "найти первый свободный в группе laboratory_prefix_id = 5, но не менее sample.sample_number = 4"):

```
SET @laboratory_prefix_id = 5;
SET @min_sample_number = 4;

SELECT @count
FROM sample, (select @count := @min_sample_number-1) dummy
WHERE sample.laboratory_prefix_id = @laboratory_prefix_id
  AND sample.sample_number > @min_sample_number-1
  AND (@count := @count+1) < sample.sample_number
ORDER BY sample.sample_number ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Недостаток - тот же.

Ну и запрос, избавленный от этого недостатка:

```
SET @laboratory_prefix_id = 5;
SET @min_sample_number = 4;

(
    SELECT @count
    FROM sample, (select @count := @min_sample_number-1) dummy
    WHERE sample.laboratory_prefix_id = @laboratory_prefix_id
      AND sample.sample_number > @min_sample_number-1
      AND (@count := @count+1) < sample.sample_number
    ORDER BY sample.sample_number ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT @min_sample_number
)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: к чему такие сложности?

Answer (score 1):

```
select s1.sample_number+1 
from sample s1 
left join sample s2 on s2.sample_number = s1.sample_number+1 AND s2.laboratory_prefix_id=5
where s1.laboratory_prefix_id=5 and s2.id is null 
order by s1.sample_number limit 1;
```

Comment: Возвращает Column 'sample_number' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: о боги. попытайся исправить эту ошибку самостоятельно

Comment: Запрос возвращает значение в любом случае. И не то, что нужно, если честно. Если запустить как есть и в order by исправить ошибку, то на представленных в вопросе данных вернёт 16 - следующий по порядку от максимального номер.

Comment: сказки свой бабушке расказывай

Comment: Ладно. На немного изменённых данных. Если убрать строку со значением sample_number=10 (т.е. останутся 1-9 и 15), то вернёт не 10, а 16 - http://i.imgur.com/63PgTyj.png

Comment: Уберите в исходных данных запись с `laboratory_prefix_id=5 AND sample_number = 1` и получите единицу. Уберите все записи с `laboratory_prefix_id=5` и получите единицу.

Comment: Он просто забыл добавить в условия связывания `AND s2.laboratory_prefix_id=5` - вот и получается неверный результат.

Comment: @Akina спасибо.