# Как выполнить запрос к БД без построителя?

Tags: yii2, pdo

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь выполнить запрос, но получаю ошибку

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception Caused by: PDOException
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Пытаюсь выполнить [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708434/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/708454#708454) (смотри ниже), но ничего не выходит. Как быть? Как запустить?

```
$query="SET @laboratory_prefix_id = 5;
    SET @min_sample_number = 1;
    (
        SELECT @count
        FROM sample, (select @count := @min_sample_number-1) dummy
        WHERE sample.laboratory_prefix_id = @laboratory_prefix_id
          AND sample.sample_number > @min_sample_number-1
          AND (@count := @count+1) < sample.sample_number
        ORDER BY sample.sample_number ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT @min_sample_number
    )
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    LIMIT 1;";
$rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```

Обычные запросы типа "SELECT * FROM table" работают и `print_r($rows)` отображает массив полученных строк.

Comment: В данном случае будет лучше, если Вы не явно будете задавать значения `@laboratory_prefix_id` и `@min_sample_number` оператором SET, а передадите их как параметры своего запроса внутрь псевдотаблицы dummy или непосредственно в текст запроса.

Comment: @Akina В итоге оказалось, что нужно не ->queryAll() , а ->execute(). Но получить результат выполнения не выходит. Про передачу параметра спасибо. Да, так и сделаю

Comment: Ну если при execute всё нормально, то можно и SET оставить... они всё одно будут жить только в пределах текущего connection.

Comment: @Akina запрос выполняется, но результат выполнения не приходит. Только `int(0)`, если сделать `var_dump($rows)`. Хотя как если выполнять запрос отдельно (через phpMyAdmin, например и др.), то результат есть. Т.е. запрос что-то возвращает.

Comment: @Akina похоже, что execute выполняет запрос и возвращает не разультат запроса, а количество строк полученных данных. Если выполнять банальный SELECT * FROM table, то вренёт количество строк в таблице.

Comment: Если верить документации http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#execute-detail , то `execute` возвращает количество изменённых запросом строк

Comment: @Akina да, а это не то. Совсем не ясно, почему нельзя выполнить запрос...

Comment: Я не увидел в описании возможности выполнить одним методом несколько запросов и получить все возвращаемые ими наборы данных. `query()` явно ориентирован на ОДИН запрос и один соответственно набор данных.

Comment: @Akina Придётся, видно, выполнять через mysqli в обход фреймворка

Comment: "Решённость" вопроса определяется наличием галочки у одного из ответов к нему. Не надо добавлять особые пометки в заголовок и тем более добавлять ответ в вопрос. Ответам место в ответах.

Comment: @D-side я не могу пока что принять свой ответ - только через  2 дня. А вопрос по сути уже решён ведь...

Comment: И эта задержка введена не просто так. За это время могут предложить решение получше. Явление редкое, но крайне полезное, когда случается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно разделить запрос на три части - вынести в отдельные запросы первые две команды SET.

```
$rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SET @laboratory_prefix_id = 5;')->execute();
$rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SET @min_sample_number = 1;')->execute();
$rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```

Или отказаться от первых двух запросов и в оставшейся части запроса просто вместо переменных вручную подставить числа

```
    (
        SELECT @count
        FROM sample, (select @count := 0) dummy
        WHERE sample.laboratory_prefix_id = 5
          AND (@count := @count+1) < sample.sample_number
        ORDER BY sample.sample_number ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT @min_sample_number
    )
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Вы должны ГАРАНТИРОВАТЬ, что все три команды будут выполнены в рамках одного соединения с БД. Иначе значения переменных останутся в одном, а запрос будет выполнен в другом, откуда эти переменные недоступны (они локальны для соединения, в каждом соединении они свои, даже если одноимённы).

Comment: И как можно это гарантировать? Создать для этого запроса отдельный объект соединения с БД? Мне казалось, что обращение `Yii::$app->db` создаёт новый объект соединения. Или у них там вшит "сингелтон", и всегда только один объект соединения с БД?

Comment: *как можно это гарантировать?* а фиг знает. Yii находится за рамками моего интереса. Кстати, если операция будет частой, можно оформить её в виде ХП или UDF, передавая туда требуемые параметры и получая результат, тогда проблемы с мультизапросами отпадут

Comment: @Akina можно же ведь сделать немного не по феншую и убрать первых два запроса вообще, подставив в запросе вместо переменных данные вручную (пример в ответе - дополнил)?

Comment: @Akina от тебя тут больше вреда чем пользы. Сначала городишь бессмысленный запрос в три этажа, потом начинаешь бегать суетиться про рамки одного соединения. Рекомендую с такой буйной фантазией переквалифицироваться в писатели дамских романов

Comment: *можно же ... убрать первых два запроса вообще* Конечно. Я просто не понял, зачем вообще использован более общий вариант, если база гарантированно = 1.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо большое! Да, в БД все номера начинаются с 1 и должны идти без пропусков. Запрос Ваш работает прекрасно!

Comment: Ну уж `1-1` замените на ноль, что ли... а заведомо истинное `AND sample.sample_number > 1-1` вообще удалите за ненадобностью.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо! Исправил

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запрос в такой форме:

```
(
    SELECT @count
    FROM sample, (select @laboratory_prefix_id := ?
                       , @min_sample_number := ?
                       , @count := @min_sample_number-1) dummy
    WHERE sample.laboratory_prefix_id = @laboratory_prefix_id
      AND sample.sample_number > @min_sample_number-1
      AND (@count := @count+1) < sample.sample_number
    ORDER BY sample.sample_number ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT @min_sample_number
)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Запрос уже подготовлен для привязки параметров (правда, не убеждён насчёт синтаксиса и корректности использования знаков вопроса как плейсхолдеров).

Правда, не нахожу гарантии, что второй запрос в UNION будет выполняться строго после первого...

Comment: Yii возвращает только это `Array ( [@count] => )`. Хотя если отдельно выполнить запрос (через phpMyAdmin, например) результат этого же запрос есть (вместо := ? я пока ставлю значения вручную)

Comment: Решил проблему. Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Большое спасибо за участие и подсказки!!!